# Development Library for NFC Reader ACR1222L

Tags: usb, nfc

Does anyone know if there exist a development library for the ACR1222L USB NFC/LCD reader/writer?  (I'm not sure if it is compatible with ACR122U or not, which libnfc is somewhat supporting it.)

[ACR1222L product page](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&prod_sections=0&id=ACR1222L)

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you actually tried libnfc? Judging from the feature description, it probably has the same or nearly the same reader chip as the ACR122U, so there is reasonable chance it will just work.

Comment: How about https://github.com/grundid/nfctools?

Comment: I am doing my due diligence before I order one for coding.  I was hoping people have tested this with libnfc or nfctools.  And I can't find any info on which NFC chip it actually run.  Appreciate any help!

Comment: libnfc doesn't seem to recognize the ACR1222L directly.  Though lsusb is able to list out the device.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you aware that there is an SDK available for the ACR122L (Serial) but not the ACR1222L (USB). These devices appear the same but the SmartCard connection methods/operations are completely different.

The ACR1222L that you are concerned about operates in a fashion that is closer to the ACR122U that it's serial counterpart (ACR122L).

I took a bunch of code that worked on the ACR122U and it also worked on the ACR1222L with little modification.

What platform are you developing on?

A good place to start would be with the ACR122U SDK then buy the ACR1222L.

I have developed for all three devices mentioned above.

Comment: What library did you use for ACR1222L?
I have de ACR 122U but need to upgrade.